# Getting layer number from layer name in MapInfo (vis MapBasic)

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

Is there a function to get the layer number from the layer name in MapBasic? I am writing a script to loop through each layer I have and apply styles and labelling. Each layer is named _#_LINE or _#_BUFFER

So I was thinking of assigning the layer number as an integer, applying the styles then incrementing the # by one so it moves onto the next layer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use LayerInfo to get from a layer name to the matching layer number and vice versa.

Use LAYER_INFO_NUM and LAYER_INFO_NAME.

Also note that you can use a layer number to change the styling of a layer. You don't need the name.

The layer number is unique where you can have multiple layers with the same name (if you have a table in the map multiple times).